# How to add clickable widgets in EditText at current position

Tags: java, android, textview, label, android-edittext

I guess the title of the question is clear enough. What I want to do is add clickable widgets like Lable or Button or TextView in an EditText which already has some text in it. These widgets should get appended to the text.

As I don't know the exact number of the widgets to be added at design time, it won't be possible to do it in xml. I must do it in Java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views just can be added to `ViewGroup`s and `EditText` is not a `ViewGroup`, so you can't do that with default `EditText` widget, and you can write your own custom `View` to implement that.

[this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) is the android documentation about custom views, and taking a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NoteEditor.html) can be useful too.